# Update manager gives updates for older kernel

Tags: updates, kernel

I upgraded my kernel to 3.9.xx from 3.2.xx. But the Update Manager still shows these updates:

Header files related to linux kernel version 3.2.0
Linux kernel headers for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
Generic Linux Kernel Headers
Linux Kernel Headers for Development

Why is the Update Manager still showing me updates for the 3.2 kernel instead of showing updates for the 3.9 kernel?

Comment: Missing details: What **Ubuntu** version are you using? Is it up-to-date, and still supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sudo apt-get autoremove

is not removing the older kernels.

Here is little discussion about that:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=996053

And here is description of how it is achieved to remove older installed kernels
with their headers:

http://ubuntugenius.wordpress.com/2011/01/08/ubuntu-cleanup-how-to-remove-all-unused-linux-kernel-headers-images-and-modules/